# Read/Write a 1gb text file without fully reading/writing it

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a script to read and write to a specefic line using a stream without actually opening and writing the whole file.

Ex: text file is 1gb big and contains over 1000 lines.
the format is..  ipv4/ipv6=current time

The current script I have is working fine for reading, but i'm having problems writing at a specefic line without having to use file put contents from an array which opens the whole file and takes lots of time.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
// Del First Char
function trimit( $string ) {
    return substr( $string, 1 );
}
// Ini the line count
$linecount = 0;
// Open File by Line
$handle = fopen("users.txt", "r+");
if ($handle) {
    // Read line
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // Trim line to time
        $alt = strstr($line, '=');
        $alt = trimit($alt);
        // IF line is older than 10 minutes, clear it
        if (time()-600 > $alt) 
        {
            $newcount = 0;
            $fp = fopen("users.txt", "w+");
            while (($line2 = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
                if ($newcount === $linecount) {
                    fwrite($fp, $line2);
                    echo "worked";
                }
                $newcount++;
            }
            fclose($fp);
        }
        $linecount++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "FATAL ERROR: Could not read file";
}
?>
```

Issue i'm having:
Rewrites the whole file and not specefic line after matched searched line by using int

Please any help or clarification would really help <3

Comment: The second argument to [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) is the mode in which the file is opened, and `r` is for `read` which won't play nicely with `fwrite()`. Also, you're not going to want to be reading from/writing to the same file simultaneously. It's not *impossible*, but it's very complicated and not something I imagine you really want to do.

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks for your quick response, I changed it to w+ because of what you said, do you know any ways to write to a specefic line without opening it?

Comment: Personally I use command line arguments such as `sed` and `grep` when dealing with files that large .. With php you can use `shell_exec()`  -- basically you'd use a `sed` command as a "search and replace" with almost zero overhead.

Comment: @Zak thanks for your suggestion, but I disabled `shell_exec()` on my server for security purposes.

Comment: Side note: You can enable shell_exec for a single script --  and disable it for everything else  ;-)

Comment: Side - side note -- There is no other way other than the more memory intensive `$data = file('myfile');` and then `file_put_contents('myfile', $data);`  --  `fopen` is the least overhead you're going to find using straight `php`.  For larger files like this you'll either have to go the `shell_exec()` route, store it in a `database`,or stick with the intense `fopen` option.

Comment: @Zak can you provide me an example using `shell_exec()` with `sed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `shell_exec()` as the OS indexes the files and your search / replace methods will have such little overhead, that you'll probably never see the impact.

The actual `linux` command is:

```
find /var/www/directory/file.txt -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i "s/string_you_are_looking_for/replacement_text/g" {} \;
```

Added to `shell_exec()` :

```
shell_exec('find /var/www/directory/file.txt -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i "s/string_you_are_looking_for/replacement_text/g" {} \;');
```

**...**  It's important to note, that I am using `/` as a delimiter, and if there are slashes in the string you want to replace, you'll have to escape them ..  IE `\/`  also some other "Linux only" items will need escaped, such as `$` and `@` IE `\$` and `\@`

**Also** note that `php` (moreover the Linux user `www-data`) will need permissions to write to the file.

Comment: Downvote with no comment?  Is my syntax incorrect?  If you see the OP -- He asked me specifically for this solution .. Please have the gall to leave a comment if you downvote, so the person with the answer can improve the solution, as to benefit the community.  "Blind voting" helps nobody.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Works fine and quickly, i've decided to change method. but i'm still using shell_exec to do the tasks i require and it's working like a charm. Thanks again!